# WatchKit backgroundImage Button change

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I want to set the background image of my button to an other image, if my button was pressed.

initial image is On or Off. if the button backgroundImage is On, i want to set it to Off, if it is Off i want to set it to On.

But there is no getter for my button. i can't use

```
self.button1.backgroundImage
```

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

here is one simple way you can do:

1.define ImageView as a subview of your button

2.define bool for changing image

when user hits the button:

```
-(void)btnTap:(id)sender{
  if(boolOne){
    ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImageView.png"];
    bool = false;
}else{
    ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"secondImageView.png"];
    bool = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WatchKit has no properties on the controls. There is value: bool not sender:AnyObject.